# How to solve Signal Cellular off error?

Tags: wi-fi, cellular-radio, network-signal

My android 9 phone acting slowly yesterday, so I restarted it. Then its cellular signal icon on top get crossed from left to right. I googled it and that is a "Signal Cellular off" icon. Now my phone could not connect to any cellular signal or WIFI(could not find any AP), but it could still acting as AP hotspot(and my laptop could connect to it).

I tried to turn on and off airplane mode, go to safe mode, reset APN, my signal icon remain crossed. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Anything without doing factory reset please.

Phone: HTC U12+
Kernel: 4.9.112
ROM Version: 2.50.709.3 10.0_g CL1099005 release-key
Last system update: Oct 2019
Something before error: misclick an ad on chrome, close it, tap my FB app to foreground and it shows me session expired and need to relogin. Then my phone seem a bit slow when I do APP switch, so I cleared all background and press restart. After passed PIN check at boot up process, my signal icons get crossed and no wifi can be found(even I'm sitting next to my WIFI AP).

Comment: Do you see any other Wifis? Remove Sim card, reboot and then reinsert Sim card. Is your device rooted or have you installed a system update recently?

Comment: @Robert no Wifi found, I did reboot my phone without SIM card and reinsert but not working, also not rooted and don't have system update for months

Comment: If there is any way to identify the source of this error, like I could find it from system log, please tell me how to find it.

Comment: Please edit your question and ad more details like the exact model name and the manufacturer of your phone. Also please include when you have installed the last system update and if you remember anything special what you have done before the error has occurred.

Comment: Basically, I don't even go to play store or installed any insecured APP from outside of store that day, so I can't recall anything really suspicious unless I'm hit by 0-day from the malicious website.

Comment: It seems very coincidental that both cellular and WiFi don't work at the same time despite being different hardware parts. Usually, [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) can give some info on what's happening on the Android device in real-time (you may also need [ADB](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2317790), [USB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers), and enabling USB debugging).

Comment: @AndrewT. HTC U12+ uses a Qualcomm Snapdragon 845 which has LTE modem and Wifi integrated into the main chip. If there would not be the working hotspot I would guess that there is a hardware failure at the antenna connection are something similar.

Comment: @AndrewT. Ok, I got logcat log, 4294 kb. Do you know the keyword that I could search inside this log?

Comment: @Robert so this situation is really odd because I could still connect to my phone's hotspot on both normal startup and safe mode even now. really weird

Comment: seem like no way to solve this but return to factory. this is it.